# How to get total in dynamically generated data

Tags: sql-server

I used used  dynamic pivot to generate data for class broad sheet but still needs to get the total score  and number of subject taken for each child.The following is the dynamic pivot query and  the result.

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(Course)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM Courses) AS Courses

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
'SELECT * FROM
(SELECT     
    [Course], 
    Total,studentcourses.StudentId As Id,fname,lname
From student 
 join StudentCourses 
 on student.StudentId = studentcourses.StudentId
 join courses 
 on studentcourses.CourseId = courses.courseid )X
    PIVOT(SUM(Total) 
          FOR Course IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

  EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

My result is as follows

```
Id  fname   lname   AgricSc BasicSc CART    English ICT Maths   PHE
1   Fatima  Abdullahi   96  97      92      97      93  97      90
2   Muhammed Abubakar   89  87      92      90      95  92      86
3   Samiat  Akere       96  94      94      99      96  97      97
4   Idris   Yakubu      80  92      96      92      80  88      84
5   Maryam  Suleiman    80  74      95      77      90  77      86
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more selectcolumns as below:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
Declare @SelectColumnNames as Nvarchar(max)

SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(Course)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM Courses) AS Courses

Select @SelectColumnNames = stuff((select Distinct '+'+QuoteName(Course) from Courses for xml path('')),1,1,'')

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
'SELECT Id,fname,lname,' + @ColumnName + ',' + @SelectColumnNames + ' as [TotalScore] FROM
(SELECT     
    [Course], 
    Total,studentcourses.StudentId As Id,fname,lname
From student 
 join StudentCourses 
 on student.StudentId = studentcourses.StudentId
 join courses 
 on studentcourses.CourseId = courses.courseid )X
    PIVOT(SUM(Total) 
          FOR Course IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: It worked thanks. Does the same method apply for count for number of subject taken per child?